# How to get Real IP when using stackpath (Magento 1)

Tags: magento-1

We have just moved to Stackpath and now our payments are failing.
I can see the requests hitting the server:

`[08/Aug/2019:09:27:41 +0000] "POST/worldpay/processing/response...`

I have enabled the debug logs and can see the error message below:

```
Worldpay response error: Domain can't be validated as WorldPay-Domain.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be because magento is failing to determine the "remote address"
`app/code/community/Phoenix/Worldpay/controllers/ProcessingController.php:165`

```php
// validate request ip coming from WorldPay/RBS subnet
        $helper = Mage::helper('core/http');
        if (method_exists($helper, 'getRemoteAddr')) {
            $remoteAddr = $helper->getRemoteAddr();
        } else {
            $request = $this->getRequest()->getServer();
            $remoteAddr = $request['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        if (!preg_match('/\.worldpay\.com$/', gethostbyaddr($remoteAddr))) {
            Mage::throwException('Domain can\'t be validated as WorldPay-Domain.');
        }
```

This can be fixed by adding the stackpath "REAL ID" header into your config.
If you edit the file `app/etc/local.xml` and add:

```xml
<remote_addr_headers>
    <header1>HTTP_X_SP_FORWARDED_IP</header1>
</remote_addr_headers>
```

Inside `config->global`
Then refresh your cache "remote address" should now be correct.

You can test this by placing the file `test-remote-address.php`

```php
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/bootstrap.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app('admin');
print_r($_SERVER);
echo 'address: '.Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
```

In your web root then requesting it with your browser. You will notice that after updating `app/etc/local.xml` it will be correct.
**Be sure to remove this file once you are happy**